# Azure Functions: Does the runtime re-start running instances upon an environment variable change?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-function-app, azure-functions-runtime

I have a `Function` app, and I'd like to understand what happens when I change environment variables on Azure Portal. Does Azure stop the running web server and re-start it for the environment changes to be picked up?

I'm re-using static variables like `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` and `StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer` so that I don't have to open and close network connections for each request. If I change the environment config for these classes, I want them to start using the new connection strings.

Comment: I can't find anything in the docs to confirm but it's what I see from my experience. Updating any of the application settings in a function app and making a request to that function's endpoint constantly results in a cold start, which implies an instance restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, app is restarted when you edit environmental variables in Azure Portal. When you try to save changes to the Configuration (including env variables and other settings), here's the popup which informs about the app's restart:

[image]